# no matching function for call to 'BinarySearchTree<Weather>::InorderTraversal(<unresolved overloaded function type>)

Tags: c++, dictionary, callback, binary-search-tree, function-pointers

I create a bst template class

```
template<class T>
using travPtr = void(*)(T&);


template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::InorderTraversal(travPtr<T> tp) const
{
    if(m_root == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    std::stack<Node<T>*> s;
    Node<T>* current;
    current = m_root;

    while((current != nullptr) || !s.empty())
    {
        while(current != nullptr)
        {
            s.push(current);
            current = current->left;
        }
        current = s.top();
        s.pop();
        tp(current->m_data);
        current = current->right;
    }
}
```

with the inorderTraversal, I want to take in a a call back function from my Vector class and add the stored data in bst and transfer it to my vector class. `Vector<Weather>`

the vector function to add data is the follow:

```
template <class T>
void Vector<T>::Add(T& data)
{
    //check if current size matches capacity
    if (m_current == m_capacity)
    {
        //multiply by 2 if it does
        T* m_temp = new T[2 * m_capacity];
        //loop through the vector
        for (int i = 0; i < m_capacity; i++)
        {
            //copy over
            m_temp[i] = m_data[i];
        }

        //destruct the array
        delete[] m_data;
        m_capacity *= 2;
        m_data = m_temp;
    }

    m_data[m_current] = data;
    m_current ++;
}
```

As both of these function are use in the `main.cpp`

```
map<Date, BinarySearchTree<Weather>> weatherMap;
Vector<Weather> tempMap;
Date keyDate(1, month, year);
if(!weatherMap.empty())
    {
        map<Date, BinarySearchTree<Weather>>::iterator it = weatherMap.find(keyDate);

        // Check if the month of the year exist in the data
        if(it != weatherMap.end())
        {
            (it->second).InorderTraversal(tempMap.Add);
        }
     }
```

the error returns that I have no matching function however when I try using a Custom print to call the function pointer. It works perfectly fine.

This is the `Print()` that works:

```
template <typename T>
void Print(T& n)
{
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: error says tempMap.Add is overloaded, but you only show one overload. Please try to create a  [mcve]

Comment: moreover `temp.Add` is a member function not a `void(*)(T&)`